# Organize mail with Evolution & Gmail IMAP

Tags: gmail, evolution

With thunderbird & Gmail POP, things are very easy. I can create filter that will automatically move the mail to the appropriate sub-folder.
However, with evolution & Gmail IMAP, I find things very messy. I cannot figure out how to create filter that will automatically move my email to a sub folder.
Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you considering evolution over thunderbird?

Comment: I find Evolution the default email client for Ubuntu (And I lost all of my mail with thunderbird due to some mistake during my last backup/restore). That's why I gave it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you would benefit from setting up a filter via Gmail's web interface to tag mail with the name of a subfolder.  Your tags in Gmail will show up as subfolders on your email client of choice.

For example, I'm using Thunderbird and Gmail, and I have a filter set up on Gmail to tag notification emails with a tag named Notification.  That tag, when I open up Thunderbird, shows up as a subfolder and I see any mail tagged as Notification in that folder.

Comment: That's true. But the email that filtered still show up in the Inbox folder. Is there any way to avoid that duplicate? (Since email will be listed twice, one in Inbox and one in the labeled sub folder)

Comment: You should be able to set the Gmail filter to archive the mail when it comes in.  This will remove it from the inbox and only keep it in the subfolder.